# Can I have a library and binary with the same name?

Tags: build, go

I'm building a library, but I also want it to be usable as a standalone binary.

For example, let's say I'm building an implementation of Tar. Tar is commonly used as a command, but it can also be used as a library. Intuitively, I'd do something like this:

```
src/
    tar/
        tar.go # belongs to package tar
        main.go # imports tar and provides a main function
```

This doesn't seem to work though. From the [documentation](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#tmp_7), it seems that "commands" should have a separate name from the library. Adapting the example given there to this example, I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
    tar/
        tar.go # belongs to package tar
    tarbin/
        main.go # imports tar and provides a main function
```

However, this creates a command called `tarbin`, not `tar` in `$GOPATH/bin`. The workaround I've found is to do `go build -o $GOPATH/bin/tar tar`, but I get the feeling I'm doing something horribly wrong. Is there a better way?

**Note:** I'm well aware that `tar` is included in the standard libs, I'm only using it as an example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd probably do this

```
src/
    tar/
        tar.go         # tar libary
        tar/
            main.go    # tar binary
```

That will give you a binary called `tar` and a library called `tar`

Let's say you are hosting this on github then you'd want

```
src/
    github.com/
        you/
            tar/
                tar.go         # tar libary
                tar/
                    main.go    # tar binary
```

Which would give you a binary called tar when you do `go get install github.com/you/tar/tar` and a library called `github.com/you/tar` when you do `go get install github.com/you/tar`

Depending on which you feel is more important you could swap the library and the binary over

```
src/
    github.com/
        you/
            tar/
                main.go            # tar binary
                tar/
                    tar.go         # tar libary
```

Keeping all the code in one tree enables you to do `go install ./...` from the root to build all packages and subpackages which is an advantage.  `go test|fmt ./...` also.  (Note that really is 3 dots!)

Comment: Except "go build" will fail because your binary would named the same as a local directory ("tar"). You must use "go build -o" in this case.

Comment: @Gravis I see what you mean.  However `go install` is what you want to use for building the binary - pretty much never use `go build` as it doesn't cache the builds.  I'll edit the response to remove the reference to `go build`.