# Install a Go binary, keep dependencies / packages

Tags: go

When I build a Go binary, I usually do something like this:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.basedir somevar" -o mybuilddir/bin/myfile mypackage/main"
```

this builds the binary and places it in a custom directory. But this doesn't keep the "intermediate" package files beneath `pkg/`, which would speed up the next compilation runs.

The solution would be `go install`, but I cannot specify an output directory. It seems to be possible to set the binary directory with `GOBIN`, but I am unable to specify the name of the executable (always `main`).

What is a possible solution to this problem?

- Custom destionation directory
- Custom name (not `main`)
- Keep intermediate generated package files (`.a`)

---

This is the `src` directory of `GOPATH`:

```
GOPATH/src$ tree 
.
└── mypackage
    ├── packagea
    │   └── packagea.go
    ├── packageb
    │   └── packageb.go
    └── main
        └── mypackage.go
```

With `go install`, the package files (`.a`) are created in `$GOPATH/pkg`, with `go build`, I can't find the `.a` files anywhere.

Comment: Did you try to add `GOPATH=mybuilddir/` before the `go build ...`? As in `GOPATH=mybuilddir go build ...`

Comment: @VonC The `GOPATH` is set and in it's `src` directory there is a directory called `mypackage` and a subdirectory called `main` with the `.go` file to be used as a `main` executable.

Comment: Ok, where is the `pkg/` created then? Not in `GOPATH/pkg`, I presume?

Comment: @VonC See my revised question: with `go install`, the `.a` files are inside `GOPATH/pkg`, with `go build`, no `.a` files are created.

Comment: This seems to help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284375/can-i-have-a-library-and-binary-with-the-same-name

Comment: The fact that you don't find .a after a go build seems expected (as I detail in my answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update Nov. 2017: Go 1.10 (Q1 2018) will add caching for go build and go install: see "[`go build` rebuilds unnecessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109826/6309)".

---

Original answer (2014)

> With `go install`, the package files (`.a`) are created in `$GOPATH/pkg`, with `go build`, I can't find the `.a` files anywhere.

As mentioned in "[How does the go build command work ?](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/15/how-does-the-go-build-command-work)"

> The final step is to pack the object file into an archive file, `.a`, which the linker and the compiler consume.
>
> **Because we invoked `go build` on a package, the result is discarded as `$WORK` is deleted after the build completes**.
>   If we invoke `go install -x` two additional lines appear in the output

```
mkdir -p /home/dfc/go/pkg/linux_arm/crypto/
cp $WORK/crypto/hmac.a /home/dfc/go/pkg/linux_arm/crypto/hmac.a
```

> This demonstrates the difference between `go build` and `install`;
>
> - `build` builds,
> - `install` builds then installs the result to be used by other builds.