# `go build` rebuilds unnecessarily

Tags: go, build

go build and go run are very slow on a tiny program I have (cgo invocations in particular).  I'd like go to cache the binary so that it only rebuilds when the source is newer.  I would use a simple Makefile with a % rule, but the language designers claim that go's build support doesn't need Makefiles.

Is there another alternative I've overlooked?  Does the go community prefer another build system, maybe hash-based instead, for caching and reusing build products?

Comment: `go install` and/or `go build -i`; they will install dependant packages that in future won't get rebuilt unless changed. A plain `go build` will rebuild changed dependant packages but won't save the results.

Comment: This is exactly what `go install` is for.

Comment: `go build -x` tells me the time is spent rebuilding the tiny program. Dependencies are cached okay.

Comment: `go install` with no arguments works, thank you! (but not `build -i`). At this point I was looking into `go list` formats, makedepends and continuous building.

Comment: See this answer for [What does go build build?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30612612/1705598)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/anacrolix/godo) that happens to solve this as a side effect. `go build` alone will not check if the executable it's producing is already up to date. `go install` does, and if you tweak it to install to a location of your choice, then you'll get the desired result, similar to `go build`.

You can see the behaviour you describe by doing something like this:

```
$ go get -d github.com/anacrolix/missinggo/cmd/nop
$ time go run "$GOPATH"/src/github.com/anacrolix/missinggo/cmd/nop/*.go

real    0m0.176s
user    0m0.142s
sys     0m0.048s
```

That's on a warm run. `go run` will link on every invocation, just as `go build` would. Note that `github.com/anacrolix/missinggo/cmd/nop` is an program that does absolutely nothing.

Here's invoking the same package, using my tool, godo:

```
$ time godo github.com/anacrolix/missinggo/cmd/nop

real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.033s
```

For larger programs, the difference should be more pronounced.

So in summary, your standard tooling option is to use `go install`, or an alternative like godo.

Answer (score 7):

`go build` and `go install` will soon (Go 1.10, Q1 2018) be much faster: see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA/X2UzjNV1BAAJ) and [this](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10) draft document.

> The go command now maintains a cache of built packages and other small metadata ([CL 68116](https://golang.org/cl/68116) and [CL 75473](https://golang.org/cl/75473)). The cache defaults to the operating system-defined user cache directory but can be moved by setting `$GOCACHE`.
>   Run "`go env GOCACHE`" to see the current effective setting. Right now the go command never deletes anything from the cache. If the cache gets too big, run "`go clean -cache`" instead of deleting the directory. That command will preserve the cache's `log.txt` file. In a few weeks I'll ask people to post their `log.txt` files to a Github issue so that we can evaluate cache size management approaches.
>
> The main effect of the build cache is that commands like "`go test`" and "`go build`" run fast and do incremental builds always, reusing past build steps as aggressively as possible.
>   You do not have to use "`go test -i`" or "`go build -i`" or "`go install`" just to get fast incremental builds. We will not have to teach new users those workarounds anymore. Everything will just be fast.

Note that `go install` won't installs dependencies of the named packages: see "[What does `go build` build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109875/6309)".