# How to make go linters ignore vendor/?

Tags: go

How do we make `go vet`, `gofmt`, and other Go linter tools ignore third-party files in `vendor/`, preferably with an accurate, cumulative exit status?

For example, would `find . -name vendor -prune -o -name '*.go' -exec gofmt -s -w {} \;` present a meaningful exit status?

Comment: Note: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19090 (for `go vet` specifically) follows that issues and reference other issues.

Comment: With go 1.10 (Q1 2018), go vet won'f fail with `uses unkeyed fields` errors when depending on vendor packages. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110039/6309)

Answer (score 9):

I usually do

```
go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
```

But since I started using `govendor` discovered I can do the same using govendor with less typing

```
govendor fmt +l // +l is shorthand for local
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually `go list` is more helpful than `find` here:

```
$ go list ./... 
arp242.net/trackwall
arp242.net/trackwall/cmdline
arp242.net/trackwall/vendor/arp242.net/sconfig
arp242.net/trackwall/vendor/bitbucket.org/pkg/inflect
[..trim..]
```

As you see, this will list all the package names in the current directory. To filter the `vendor` directory we can use `grep`:

```
$ go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/
arp242.net/trackwall
arp242.net/trackwall/cmdline
```

If you want to run several linters, report all errors, and return `0` only if there is a success, you could use a loop and a status variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

st=0
for pkg in $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/); do
    echo "==> $pkg"

    go vet "$pkg"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && st=1

    golint "$pkg"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && st=1

    # gofmt works on files, not packages
    gofmt -d "${f#arp242.net/trackwall}"*.go
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && st=1
done
exit $st
```

Which will output something like:

```
==> arp242.net/trackwall
http.go:71: database/sql.NullString composite literal uses unkeyed fields
exit status 1
/home/martin/gocode/src/arp242.net/trackwall/http.go:70:2: don't use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase
/home/martin/gocode/src/arp242.net/trackwall/http.go:75:9: if block ends with a return statement, so drop this else and outdent its block
==> arp242.net/trackwall/cmdline
Exit 1
```

---

Of course, you're not the first one with this problem, and there are tools which basically do the same as above, except better. [gometalinter](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter) is probably the best known and I recommend you use this. It helpfully includes a `--vendor` switch to ignore the vendor directory:

```
$ go get -u github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter

$ gometalinter --vendor ./...
helpers.go:25:1:warning: realpath is unused (deadcode)
http.go:32:1:warning: _list is unused (deadcode)
[..trim..]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions! This works for my purposes:

https://github.com/mcandre/go-ios7crypt/blob/ea8dd957e8f146ea20a57122870008a968875b53/Makefile

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use:

```
golint $(ls -d1 */ | sed s/\\//\\/.../g | grep -v -E "^vendor/" | tr "\n" " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your source code into a subdirectory (e.g. `internal` or `lib`). Alternatively, you can do this:

```
go vet ./... | grep -v vendor/ && exit 1 || exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With Go 1.10 (Q1 2018), the [kind of tips](https://github.com/mcandre/go-ios7crypt/blob/ea8dd957e8f146ea20a57122870008a968875b53/Makefile#L21-L22) mentioned by the [OP mcandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350106/mcandre)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40851203/6309) will be more robust:

```
go list ./... | grep -v vendor | xargs go vet -v
```

As illustrated in [carpetsmoker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40532504/6309), a `go vet` on packages depending on (yet non-compiled) vendored packages will fail:

```
==> arp242.net/trackwall
http.go:71: database/sql.NullString composite literal uses unkeyed fields
```

Note anymore, since [go issue 16086](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16086) is resolved!

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA/X2UzjNV1BAAJ):

> ### Go vet
>
> The "`go vet`" command works best with full type information for the packages it is analyzing. Historically that's been problematic in a variety of situations: packages using `cgo`, packages using vendoring, and packages that don't have up-to-date installed dependencies have all been things that kept `vet` from running with full type information.
>
> Not anymore. **The "`go vet`" command now passes to `vet` full information about all these things**, building new `.a` files if needed (CL 74355 and CL 74750).
>   Now "`go vet`" is guaranteed to have up-to-date type information when it analyzes a package, which will improve the accuracy of its analyses.
>   Having the [**build cache**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109826/6309) to amortize the cost of building those `.a` files was the final piece needed to make this happen.
>
> Only "`go vet`" has this guarantee. Do not use "`go tool vet`", which is essentially only useful to people working on `vet` (just like you don't typically run "`go tool compile`").
>   Previously you needed to use "`go tool vet`" if you wanted control over vet flags, but "`go vet`" now accepts all the flags that "`go tool vet`" does. (See "`go help vet`".)

Answer (score 0):

In a cross platform fashion i do this `philea -s "666 go vet %s" "666 go-fmt-fail %s"`

yields,

```
$ ls -alh | grep ven
drwxr-xr-x  5 mh-cbon mh-cbon 4,0K 14 juin  20:43 vendor
$ philea -s "666 go vet %s" "666 go-fmt-fail %s"
go-fmt-fail ./local/local.go
 ✔ Success
go-fmt-fail ./dl/index.go
 ✔ Success
go vet ./local/local.go
 ✔ Success
go-fmt-fail ./gh/gh.go
 ✔ Success
go vet ./main.go
 ✔ Success
go vet ./gh/gh.go
 ✔ Success
go vet ./dl/index.go
 ✔ Success
go-fmt-fail ./main.go
 ✔ Success
```

Comment: I'm not sure what philae is, and have failed to find out on my own, you should probably link to whatever that is

Comment: those stuff here https://github.com/mh-cbon/philea and here https://github.com/mh-cbon/go-fmt-fail and also this https://github.com/mh-cbon/666

Answer (score 0):

In Go 1.9, a [change](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/fa1d54c2edad607866445577fe4949fbe55166e1) was introduced for `./...` to no longer match packages in the `vendor` directory ([release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot)), which was a popular [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19090).

This means that for most purposes, the easiest way is now

```sh
go test ./...  # ignores vendor
go fmt ./...   # ignores vendor
go list ./...  # ignores vendor
# etc.
```

However, specifically for `gofmt` (which we might want to use if `go fmt` doesn't have the option we need), the case is not as clear cut:

- `gofmt` takes paths as arguments, not packages
- it works recursively if given directories, so it seems like just `gofmt .` should work – but that does *not* ignore `vendor`

So either we have to go back to

```sh
gofmt -l . | grep -v vendor
```

but this would match `vendor` for a directory that is *not* the actual vendor directory, and it feels wasteful to check everything in `vendor` before throwing it away.

We also can't use

```sh
gofmt -l $(go list -f '{{.Dir}}' ./...)
```

because `./...` matches the package of the current directory, causing `gofmt` to descend everywhere including `vendor`.

A more robust solution using templates iterating over the files directly

```sh
gofmt -l $(go list -f '{{range .GoFiles}} {{$.Dir}}/{{.}}{{end}}' ./...)
```

can run into command line length limitations in a large directory tree with longs paths, so that's not perfect either. My inclination is to use `go fmt ./...` where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If under Makefile(as we usually do):

```
gofmt:
    gofmt -l $(shell find . -type f -name '*.go'| grep -v "/vendor/\|/.git/") # ignore vendor and .git dir
```

> How to add `\t` before `gofmt` on StackOverflow web page? -__-