# Writing a Go program that acts as an executable as well as a module

Tags: node.js, go

I am currently trying to do my first steps in Go. Now I've ported a tool that I once written in Node.js, and I was surprised how easy that was, and how clean and concise the code is.

Anyway, I've got a question that I was not able to figure out by myself so far: In Node.js it's possible to add the `main` entry as well as the `bin` entry to the `package.json` file. This basically means that you can create a module that works as a executable when installed using

```
$ npm install -g <module>
```

but as a library when installed using

```
$ npm install <module>
```

The trick here is that the first one uses the `bin` entry, which then internally uses a file from the module's `lib` folder, but the second version directly points to this `lib` file.

So ... now I would like to have the same behavior in Go: I would like to write a package that you can directly run as an executable, but that as well you can import into another application as a library. How would I do that?

Obviously I can't put two calls to `package` into a `.go` file. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the solution in the following blog post? http://dan.munckton.co.uk/blog/2013/06/21/go-lang-packaging-creating-a-library-that-bundles-an-executable/

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284575/1333873 (which is mentioned in the blog post), and this perfectly answers my question, I think. Thanks :-)