# Having multiple main functions on Go

Tags: go, task

As a Python and Django developer, I can run any piece of code in my project using a script independently.

I am not too sure how to achieve the same thing in Go, as it looks like each Go project should only have one main executable file.

I'd like to call a function in my project from cronjob, but I'm not too sure how to add that. Using flags in my main function is the only way I can think of doing this. But it will look pretty confusing if my script accepts additional flags by itself like the following:

```
go run server.go --debug --another-flag --script-name <MY-SCRIPT> --my-script-flag-one <FLAG-ONE> --my-script-flag-two <FLAG-TWO>
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You may find this question useful: [What is a sensible way to layout a Go project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14867452/142162)

Comment: Make the piece of code a package and a command. For example, [Can I have a library and binary with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284375/can-i-have-a-library-and-binary-with-the-same-name/14284575)

Comment: some of the confusion is thinking of go as a scripting language.  `go run` should definitely not be used for things other than playing around with a small test, e.g. something you'd otherwise put on `play.golang.org`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I reference in "[What is a sensible way to layout a Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870666/6309)" the article "[Structuring Applications in Go](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091)", which shows as an example the project **[perkeep](https://perkeep.org/)**.
That project includes [*several* cmd packages](https://github.com/perkeep/perkeep), each with their own set of options.

The other option would be to use a CLI interface library like [`spf13/cobra`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra), which allows you to define several *commands* (same exe, separate sets of options).

> `Command` is the central point of the application.
> Each interaction that the application supports will be contained in a `Command`.
> A command can have children commands and optionally run an action.

> In the example "`hugo server --port=1313`", '`server`' is the command

> A `Command` has the following structure:

```
type Command struct {
    Use string // The one-line usage message.
    Short string // The short description shown in the 'help' output.
    Long string // The long message shown in the 'help <this-command>' output.
    Run func(cmd *Command, args []string) // Run runs the command.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple main function in go but the package should be declared main. This way you can have multiple go scripts/file inside package main where each file will have main function. To run a file, you can directly execute the file like `go run file.go` which will only execute the main function of file you called.

Comment: the GO compiler will complain if the new main() function (also package: main) is in a file which is in the same folder as another file of package main with a main() function. Multiple main() functions can co-exist if the file is in a separate folder (still of package main). So a new folder is needed per main() function

Comment: This is so annoying: "So a new folder is needed per main() function"

Comment: No, there will be a package main. In that package you can create multiple files where each file can have there own main function.