# GO | create 2 different executables on the same module

Tags: go, makefile

I would like to know if it is possible to create 2 different executables on the same module,
main1.go -> main1.exe
main2.go -> main2.exe

```
root
    -> main2.go
    -> main1.go
```

the goal is to run Makefile, which will create 2 different executables.
Thanks

```
LATE_TARGET_HOOK=make_main
LATE_TARGET_HOOK=make_client
DS_CONF = ds.conf

export GOROOT := $(UV_golang_PKG)
export GOPROXY := http://****-product.****.com:****/artifactory/api/go/go
export GOSUMDB := off

export PATH := $(PATH):$(GOROOT)/bin
export VERSION := $(shell (cat $(SRCROOT)/VERSION))
GO =$(GOROOT)/bin/go

CONF_FILES = VERSION

include $(MODULEMK)

ifndef UV_BUILDNUMBER
    UV_BUILDNUMBER = 0000
endif

make_main:
    ${GO} mod tidy
    GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux CGO_CFLAGS=$(CGO_CFLAGS) CGO_LDFLAGS=$(CGO_LDFLAGS) $(GO) build $(BUILD_FLAGS) -o $(SRCROOT)/CMpub/bin/$(UV_O)/agentExporters .

make_client:
    ${GO} mod tidy
    GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux CGO_CFLAGS=$(CGO_CFLAGS) CGO_LDFLAGS=$(CGO_LDFLAGS) $(GO) build $(BUILD_FLAGS) -o $(SRCROOT)/CMpub/bin/$(UV_O)/disableCollector .
```

Comment: Yes this is possible but not with your go build commands. Refactor.

Comment: A module can produce two executables, but a single package cannot.  Create a package for each executable.

Comment: How it is can be done?

Answer (score 0):

> > but a single package cannot. Create a package for each executable.
>
> How it is can be done?

By using different cmd packages inside your project, as I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27142591/6309).

This is described in details with "**[Packing multiple binaries in a Golang package](https://ieftimov.com/posts/golang-package-multiple-binaries/)** " in 2018, by **[Ilija Eftimov](https://ieftimov.com/)**

```
› tree
.
└── cmd
    ├── cookie
    │   └── main.go
    └── eight_ball
        └── main.go
```

A `go install ./...` would find those main packages and compile/install them separately.

---

A more modern/different approach would be with "[**Getting started with multi-module workspaces**](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces)": you could work on different modules (one per command) within the same workspace.

> With multi-module workspaces, you can tell the Go command that you’re writing code in multiple modules at the same time and easily build and run code in those modules.